# Determine drift

Tags: trend, measurement, calibration, concept-drift, data-drift

I would like to determine potential drift in the data/device. Is there a general acknowledged procedure and/or method to do so?
I know how to visually "detect" a drift but I would like to know how to describe it mathematically. And also how to prove it statistically.

Btw, is there a difference between drift and trend? I guess the later applies only to a time series while the first one doesn't need to?